# MySQL - Join order number of latest order based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm selecting one customer from `customers` table and trying to get the latest order number for the customer from a `jobs` table, but based on a different timestamp column in that table.

**Customers**

```
id  |  name | ...
```

**Jobs**

```
id  | customer_id  |  order_id | assigned
----------------------------------------------------
1   | 985          |  8020     | 2015-12-03 00:00:00
2   | 985          |  4567     | 2015-04-19 00:00:00
3   | 985          |  9390     | 2016-20-01 00:00:00
4   | 985          |  6381     | 2015-08-26 00:00:00
```

The latest `order_id` which should be joined is **9390** because the `assigned` timestamp is the latest.

**SQL**

```
SELECT c.name, j.latest_order
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id,
           ??? AS latest_order
    FROM jobs
    WHERE withdrawn IS NULL
    GROUP BY customer_id
) j ON j.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 985
```

I can't really figure out the best way to get the `latest_order` in the sub query, but it should be the `jobs.order_id` where `jobs.assigned = MAX(jobs.assigned)` for that customer.

Comment: do you want a table with **all** the customer and their latest order, or just for a specific **one**?

Comment: @OscarAnthony Just a specific one. I always know the customer ID I want.

Comment: okay. then just sort the orders of the customer and take the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one more derived table to get the order number for the latest order.

```
SELECT c.name, t.order_id, j.latest_order
FROM customers c
JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id,
           max(assigned) AS latest_order
    FROM jobs
    WHERE withdrawn IS NULL
    GROUP BY customer_id
) j ON j.customer_id = c.id 
JOIN (select customer_id, order_id, assinged 
      from jobs 
      where withdrawn is null) t
    ON t.customer_id = j.customer_id and t.assigned = j.latest_order
WHERE c.id = 985
```

Comment: Makes sense. Is this the only or most efficient way to do it?

Comment: No. One more way is, you can just `join` with the `jobs` table if there were no `where withdrawn is null` condition.

Comment: you can also do it just by sorting the orders of that specific customer (as you already know his id) and take the first (most recent) one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the fastest way but maybe you want to try an explain against the alternate answer to compare both performances:

```
SELECT c.name, j.latest_order
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT j1.customer_id, j1.order_id 
  FROM jobs j1 
  JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, max(assigned) as maxassigned
    FROM jobs j2
    WHERE withdrawn IS NULL
    GROUP BY customer_id
  ) j2
  ON j1.customer_id = j2.customer_id and j1.assigned = j2.maxassigned) j
ON j.customer_id = c.id
AND c.id = 985;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know the customer_id, you can achieve this in a simpler and shorter way. You just need to select all the orders of that customer, sort them by date and return only the first record.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT r.name, r.order, r.assigned
FROM (
    SELECT c.name AS name, j.order_id AS order, j.assigned AS assigned
    FROM customer c
    INNER JOIN jobs j
    ON AND c.id = j.customer_id
    WHERE c.id = 985 AND j.withdrawn IS NULL) r
ORDER BY r.assigned DESC
LIMIT 1
```